# How to add a column containing the occcurence of every element in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a DataFrame such as

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [700, 700, 600, 600, 600]}
```

How can I extend it with a column containing the occurrence for each row? Such that it ends up as

```
df_ext = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':          [700, 700, 600, 600, 600],
    'Occurrence': [  2,   2,   3,   3,   3]
})
```

Adding the column is not so much of a problem, rather how to get the occurrence list.

Answer (score 3):

You can transform `groupby_count`:

```
df['Occurrences'] = df.groupby('a')['a'].transform('count')
```

or you can map `value_counts` on "a":

```
df['Occurrences'] = df['a'].map(df['a'].value_counts())
```

Output:

```
     a  Occurrences
0  700            2
1  700            2
2  600            3
3  600            3
4  600            3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['occurance']=df['a'].map(df.groupby('a').agg('size'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use:

```
df['b'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: list(df['a']).count(x))
```